# What's the best way to enlarge the height of image to max-height?

Tags: html, css

I have a container to display image, the container has a fixed 100% width. My requirements are:

- The image doesn't change the aspect ratio
- If the image is more wide, the width is 100%, the height should be less than `max-height`.
- If the image is more high, the height should be the `max-height`, width is less than 100%.

In my example, the first two images display correct. However, the third image is wrong, because the width is not reach 100% or the height is not reach the max height.

How can I fix this issue?

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZPXw.png" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfTIL.png" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/62345e20906dbccbf7e18f11ab4bd047?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
</div>
```

You can play here as well: https://jsfiddle.net/d425c1bh/2/

Comment: So... to clarify... any must be expanded (or contracted) (keeping the aspect ratio) until it reaches or well the 100% or the width or well the max height. Right?

Comment: @Dknacht, sorry I just found the code cannot reproduce my real issue, let me update.

Comment: @Dknacht, question no issue confirmed. Yeps, you are right, either reach 100% width or 100% max-height

Comment: Please check the answer.

Comment: The img tag is an empty tag, so dont use `<img></img>` use `<img />` instead. check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: @Dknacht thanks for your suggestion. yeah, `<img />` is better.

Comment: I see that if the image is wider than the container, its getting out of bounds... is it ok?

Comment: @Dknacht I saw that issue as well, so it's not correct. I updated my description.

Comment: @Dknacht, I added `max-width: 100%` to `img`, so it won't be out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, adding [object-fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) and replacing the width auto with width 100%

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wuvbhza7/1/)

Comment: Works like a charm!. If someone wants to see it working there is a Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wuvbhza7/1/